# Css page counter reset

Tags: php, html, css, counter, dompdf

Im using Dompdf to create pdf files and to not get huge files i create multiple pdf files at once.
*(Talking about 1.4 mb instead of >300)*

So the plan is to add first pdf, add a page break and then reset the counter to 1.

Then add second pdf which starts with page counter 1 instead of continuing with 3.

Pseudo code:

```
model
    ->addContent(fooHtml)
    ->pageBreak() // adds "<div class="page_break"></div>" to content
    ->counterReset() // should add the counter reset to content 
    ->addContent(barHtml)
    ->getPdf
```

Example pdf:

[image]

The problem is the `counter-reset` does not work. The `counter-increment` does.

I now thought i could reset the counter by using the increment minus the current counter value:

`counter-increment: page -counter(page)`

But `counter(page)` does not return the value? At least it seems invalid.

This works:

`counter-increment: page -2`

but for sure is no solution.

I now search a way to get the `counter(page)` value to be able to add a div to reset the current counter to 1:

`<div style="counter-increment: page -counter(page)"></div>`.

**Is there any way to subtract the current counter?**

Here is are the test files:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Pages Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: -160px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .page_break {
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        .page_number:after {
            content: counter(page);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<footer>
    <div class="page page_number">Page&nbsp;</div>
</footer>
<div class="foo">Page One Of Foo</div>
<div class="page_break"></div>

<div class="foo">Page Two Of Foo</div>
<div style="counter-increment: page -2"></div>
<!-- does not work: <div style="counter-increment: page -counter(page)"></div> -->
<div class="page_break"></div>

<div class="foo">Page One Of Bar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$html = file_get_contents('path/to/html/template.html');

$domPdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
$domPdf->loadHtml($html);
$domPdf->render();
$pdf = $domPdf->output();
```

Comment: So maybe a [counter-increment](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/494#issuecomment-11108064)

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai Sure - this works as i wrote above. The problem is how can i set the counter dynamically since i dont know on what page i am (dyn content). I tried `counter-increment: page -counter(page)` which seems invalid (i read that this wont work because the value of counter is not an integer). Im searching a workaround|trick|hack|w/e :)

Comment: It's a long time ago, but did you find a solution? I am now also facing the same problem.

Comment: I use `<div style="counter-reset: page 1"></div>` for resetting the page. But this is not 100% working. The first page after the reset (e.g. Page 4) shows 1 (correct), but then the 2nd page after the reset shows then e.g. 5 if it is the 5th page of all....

Comment: Got no solution. Last time i tried i found out that you cannot change|update the increment in CSS (not a dompff problem). See in my question: `counter-increment: page -counter(page)` --this did not work. Perhaps it changed in the mean time? I did not checked that.